# Safely traversing a directed acyclic graph

Tags: rust, lifetime, directed-acyclic-graphs, graph-traversal

I'm attempting to build and traverse a DAG. There seems to be two feasible approaches: use `Rc<RefCell<Node>>` for edges, or utilize an arena allocator and some `unsafe` code. ([See details here.](https://aminb.gitbooks.io/rust-for-c/content/graphs/index.html))

I'm opting for the former, but having difficulty traversing the graph to its edges, as any borrow of a child node relies on borrows to its parents:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

// See: https://aminb.gitbooks.io/rust-for-c/content/graphs/index.html,
//      https://github.com/nrc/r4cppp/blob/master/graphs/src/ref_graph.rs
pub type Link<T> = Rc<RefCell<T>>;

pub struct DagNode {
    /// Each node can have several edges flowing *into* it, i.e. several owners,
    /// hence the use of Rc. RefCell is used so we can have mutability
    /// while building the graph.
    pub edge: Option<Link<DagNode>>,

    // Other data here
}

// Attempt to walk down the DAG until we reach a leaf.
fn walk_to_end(node: &Link<DagNode>) -> &Link<DagNode> {
    let nb = node.borrow();
    match nb.edge {
        Some(ref prev) => walk_to_end(prev),
        // Here be dragons: the borrow relies on all previous borrows,
        // so this fails to compile.
        None => node
    }
}
```

I could modify the reference counts, i.e.

```
fn walk_to_end(node: Link<HistoryNode>) -> Link<HistoryNode> {
    let nb = node.borrow();
    match nb.previous {
        Some(ref prev) => walk_to_end(prev.clone()),
        None => node.clone()
    }
}
```

but bumping the reference counts every time you traverse a node seems like quite the hack. What is the idiomatic approach here?

Comment: Have you read this http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/fourth-iteration.html#iter ?  Although it is about `Rc` queues, it can really help you.

Comment: ...If I'm reading the section correctly, the author ran face-first into the same problem I'm having and gave up. To wit, "Rc<RefCell> has really truly finally failed us."

Comment: @MattKline: That's actually "Anyway, that's me giving up on Iter and IterMut. We could do them, but ugh.", so it Gankro's mind it's possible, but maybe not elegant.

Comment: Yeah, looks like there is no way with `Rc<RefCell>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rc isn't really a problem here: if you get rid of the RefCells, everything just compiles.  Actually, in some situations, this might be a solution: if you need to mutate the contents of the node, but not the edges, you can just change your data structure so the edges aren't inside a RefCell.

The argument also isn't really the problem; this compiles:

```
fn walk_to_end(node: &Link<DagNode>) -> Link<DagNode> {
    let nb = node.borrow();
    match nb.edge {
        Some(ref prev) => walk_to_end(prev),
        None => node.clone()
    }
}
```

The problem here is really returning the result. Basically, there isn't any way to write the return value you want.  I mean, you could theoretically make your method return a wrapper around a `Vec<Ref<T>>`, but that's a lot more expensive than just bumping the reference count on the result.

More generally, `Rc<RefCell<T>>` is difficult to work with because it's a complicated data structure: you can safely mutate multiple nodes at the same time, and it keeps track of exactly how many edges reference each node.

Note that you don't have to dip into unsafe code to use an arena.  https://crates.io/crates/typed-arena provides a safe API for arenas.  I'm not sure why the example you linked to uses UnsafeCell; it certainly isn't necessary.